# reduxForm() Connected React Component Unit Test using Jest with NO Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, redux-form

I'm stumped in getting my Jest unit test to pass.

I have a class which provides a password form, containing the following:

```js
// Password.jsx

...

static propTypes = {
  checkPasswordRules: PropTypes.func,
  content: PropTypes.object
};

...

validatePassword(password, allFields) {
  const { confirmPassword = '' } = allFields;

  const errors = this.props.checkPasswordRules({
    password,
    confirmPassword
  });

  return errors.password ? errors.password.friendly : undefined;
}

...

get formContent() {
  ...

  return (
    <Field
       type="password"
       component={this.formField}
       name="password"
       label={content.passwordLabel}
       error={content.errorContent}
       validate={this.validatePassword}
    />
  );
}

...

export default reduxForm({ form: 'passwordForm' })(Password);
```

And here is my unit test (*Jest*):

```js
// Password.test.js

...

it('handles validatePassword method', () => {
  const allValues = { password: 'password', confirmPassword: 'password1' };
  const labels = content.passwordStrengthRules;
  const expected = labels.confirmMatchLabel;
  const component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Password {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );
  const instance = component.getInstance();
  const result = instance.validatePassword(allValues.password, allValues);

  expect(result).toEqual(expected);
});
```

The issue I am having is that when I try to run the Jest test, I am getting an error saying that `instance.validatePassword` is not a function in the console.

I am not exactly sure why that is coming up, as I am getting the `instance` right from the `component` variable within the unit test, using `react-test-renderer`. It is coming up that the above is not a function because it is looking for the `instance` of the `Provider`, which is not what I want to do. But, `render`ing the component (*in the test*) without the `Provider` throws an error that the component must be wrapped in a `Provider`!

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here...? Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I am at a legitimate standstill here...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Since, in this context, `instance` was only finding the instance of the wrapped / connected reduxForm component - `Provider` - I was unable to access the methods of the un-connected component - `Password`.

By using the following, I was able to access the class methods of `Password`

```js
it('handles validatePassword method', () => {

  ...

  const component = renderer.create(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Password {...props} />
      </Provider>
    );

  ...

  const instance = component.root.findByType(Password).instance;
  instance.validatePassword();
});
```

If anyone ever has the same issue, I hope this answer comes useful to them...